# fluentd/influxdb: Influxdb write only string data

Tags: influxdb, fluentd, grafana

I have fluentd + InfluxDB + Graphite + Grafana.
I need to apply math operations with number data, but InfluxDB or Grafana regard my numeric data like a string. So I can't compare with WHERE statements or color with grafana.
How I can set data type?

My configuration is like this:

```html
<source>
 @type http
 port 12102
 format tsv
 keys string1,string2,number1,number2
 delimiter |
</source>

<match test>
 @type copy
 <store>
  @type graphite
  tag_for prefix
  name_keys number1,number2
  host localhost
  port 2003
 </store>
 <store>
  @type influxdb
  dbname test
  flush_interval 10s
  host localhost
  port 8086
 </store>
</match>
```

And the input is like this:

```
curl -X POST -d "text1|text2|764.2|57" "http://localhost:12102/test?time=1461940658"
```

On graphite it's all OK.

Comment: Why not share your current write statement and the resulting data then we can see what is going on. It is possible that you've written a string to the field at some point and InfluxDB is now assuming the field is a string.

Comment: I updated the main post with the code and an input example.

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using?